# I want to create NDVI of multiple raster using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator, ndvi, multi-band, for-loop

I have multiple raster data which are layer stack. Now I want to create NDVI of each raster data. I am stuck in the code, I developed a script but dose not generate any output.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\Arcpy\Data\\raster_data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_raster = arcpy.ListRasters()
outputDir = ("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\NDVI")
print(input_raster)

for data in input_raster:
    red = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_red.img", "", "", "3")  # Name changed
    nir = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_nir.img", "", "", "4")  # Name changed
    # the first part of the file name before extension (if present) then add .img
    output = os.path.join(outputDir,os.path.splitext(data)[0].split('_')[0] + '_ndvi' + '.img')
    ndvi = (Float(nir) - Float(red)) / (Float(nir) + Float(red))
    print("{}\n{}".format(output, ndvi))
    ndvi.save(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included any lines that would create any output.  Also, your question doesn't specify what output you want.  So I'll take a punt...

You've generated a file path presumably to save to (`output`) and an in-memory raster object (`ndvi`), but you haven't yet done anything with either of them.  I'm guessing that you want to save `ndvi` to `output`?

Try adding the following line at the end:

`ndvi.save(output)`

Comment: I have 10 raster image. So I want to generate ndvi of each raster.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I added the ndvi.save(output) line but output was not generated.

Comment: Add some print lines to see what's going on.  FIRSTLY, just above the `for` line, add `print input_raster`.  SECONDLY, just above the `ndvi.save()` line, add `print "{}\n{}".format(output, ndvi)`.  What output do you get printed?

Comment: I added two lines, which are mention above. But output is not generated.

Comment: When you say "output is not generated", so you mean that nothing is printed, or that no files are created? (or both?)  If nothing is printed, please explain how you are running the script (eg, in the ArcMap python console, on a command line prompt, in an IDE, etc).  If nothing is printed from a print statement with a string literal, then something is going wrong with your your running the script.

Answer (score 0):

The function *arcpy.ListRasters()* does not have any argument. It reads all rasters placed in the folder defined in *arcpy.env.workspace*. The same is *arcpy.ListFeatureClasses*. Replace

```
input_raster = arcpy.ListRasters("L:\\Arcpy\Data\\raster_data")
```

with

```
input_raster = arcpy.ListRasters()
```

Also, you have a mistake at these rows:

```
red = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data, 
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul.img", "", "", "3")
nir = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data, 
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul.img", "", "", "4")
```

You created raster "red", but you overwrite it with raster "nir". You have to have a different file names, like:

```
red = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data, 
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_red.img", "", "", "3")  # Name changed
nir = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data, 
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_nir.img", "", "", "4")  # Name changed
```

**EDIT:** My bad, arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management required full path. Rollback edit. But finally you have to add raster definition. I tryied this version of your code and it works for me:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\Arcpy\Data\\raster_data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_raster = arcpy.ListRasters()
outputDir = "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\NDVI"
print(input_raster)

for data in input_raster:
    red = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
    "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_red.img", "", "", "3")
    nir = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
    "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_nir.img", "", "", "2")
    raster_red = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_red.img")
    raster_nir = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\raster_data\\Anugul_nir.img")
    # the first part of the file name before extension (if present) then add *.img
    output = os.path.join(outputDir,os.path.splitext(data)[0].split('_')[0] +
    '_ndvi' + '.img')
    ndvi = (Float(raster_nir) - Float(raster_red)) / (Float(raster_nir) + Float(raster_red))
    print("{}\n{}".format(output, ndvi))
    ndvi.save(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, the script is perfectly running now.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. If this is the right answer, mark it as accepted, please.